# Ruby uri module parsing produces nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

My ruby file is using the Ruby `uri` module as such:

```
require 'uri'

def parse_uri(uri)           # uri       => www.google.com
    uriParsed = URI(uri)     # uriParsed => <URI::Generic 0x000000000 URL:www.google.com>
    uriHost = uriParsed.host # uriHost   => nil
```

Expected behavior as per stated in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) should produce `google.com` for `uriHost`. However, that is not the case; I've tried restarting my Rails server, running `bundle install`, and requiring `uri/http` but to no avail. Any ideas?

---

Ruby version is 2.1.4, rails version is 4.0.1

Comment: hey and if you want to parse out the `www.` prefix i'll write something up to do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `.path` on `URI`:

```
require 'uri'

def parse_uri(uri)           # uri       => www.google.com
    uriParsed = URI.parse(uri)     # uriParsed => <URI::Generic 0x000000000 URL:www.google.com>
    uriHost = uriParsed.path# uriHost   => nil
```

OR.

```
def parse_uri(uri)           # uri       => www.google.com
    uriParsed = URI.parse(uri).path
```

Actually `URI(uri)` returns the same object than calling it with `.parse` so it seem a little redundant. Here is your original approach with `.path` instead of `.host`:

```
def parse_uri(uri)           # uri       => www.google.com
    uriParsed = URI(uri)     # uriParsed => <URI::Generic 0x000000000 URL:www.google.com>
    uriHost = uriParsed.path# uriHost   => nil
```

Lastly, if you want to omit the `www.` prefix if the url contains it you can do something like this:

```
require 'uri'

def parse_uri(uri)           # uri       => www.google.com
    uriParsed = URI(uri)     # uriParsed => <URI::Generic 0x000000000 URL:www.google.com>
    uriHost = uriParsed.path# uriHost   => nil
    uriHost.start_with?('www.') ? uriHost[4..-1] : uriHost

end
```

Comment: `.path` returns what I thought `.host` was for. Not sure why the doc's state that `.path`returns only the relative pathname of the URI. I tested with `http://google.com/test/test` with `.path` which returned `google.com/test/test` instead of `/test/test/`

Comment: got you. Made some final modifications to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify protocol:

```
parse_uri('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: I'm trying to parse any 'valid' URL. That would be a union of `www.google.com`, `http://www.google.com`, `google.com`.

Comment: @Xenyal Your definition of "valid" strongly contradicts what valid actually is. You'll need to prefix strings like `www.google.com` with `http://` since that's just a bare hostname and not a URL otherwise.

Comment: @tadman You're right. What I meant was any string that can be consumed by a browser to form a URL.

Comment: @Xenyal Browsers automatically and sometimes transparently pre-pend `http://` on arbitrary strings like that. You'll have to do the same.

Comment: @tadman Yeah I realized. My eventual fix does include that; I guess my question was asked in the hopes that the built-in uri module is able to handle similar tasks